# Spark Scala UDF NullPointer Exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nullpointerexception, user-defined-functions

I am trying to split and convert a column containg data in below format into map inside a udf.

UDF:

```
def convertToMapUDF = udf((c: String) => {
  val arr = c.split(",")
  val l = arr.toList
  
  val regexPattern = ".*(=).*".r
  
  println(s"column value: $c")
  
  s"$c" match {
    case regexPattern(a) => Some(l.map(x => x.split("=")).map(a => a(0).toString -> a(1).toString).toMap)
    case "null" => Some(Map[String, String]())
  }
})

val splitColList = List("r_split")
val d = ft.select(splitColList.map(c => convertToMapUDF(col(c))): _*)
```

r_split columns contains data like

```
null
null
As=true, eMsion_New:E=true, HR:E=true, Don:E=true, Hrs=true, PAD:E=true, mog:E=true, N4k:E=true, WY:E=true, AT:E=true, Dt_RFC:E=true, DASH_ALL:E=true, TE:E=true, C_14:E=true, We:E=true, PG:E=true, ZR:E=true, MP:E=true, m2M:E=true, HC:E=true, Nos:E=true,
null
```

Exception:

```
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3712.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 3712.0 (TID 37567, 10.73.35.140, executor 48): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$$$7a8ac347ba800d5b55403548fd65e2$$$$w$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$Lambda$10845/2054440395: (string) => map<string,string>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage2.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:733)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.UnsafeRowBatchUtils$.encodeUnsafeRows(UnsafeRowBatchUtils.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.$anonfun$processFunc$1(Collector.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.doRunTask(Task.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:117)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$9(Executor.scala:655)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1581)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:658)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at line6ec706fd41324bde944dab3ff50b81c6224.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$$$7a8ac347ba800d5b55403548fd65e2$$$$w$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.$anonfun$convertToMapUDF$1(command-1649645762990220:2)
    ... 14 more
```

I tried to use Option and Some but the issue is not being resolved.
The udf when executing as independant function on above string is working fine.

Comment: Is "null" a string? Or should you be creating `case null` or `case _`?

Comment: null is coming in as string

Comment: When I create a sample df using the r_split example, the UDF is working fine.

Comment: But does not work if I include the actual null value in the dataframe!

Answer (score 1):

The last line is unnecessary confusing and not relevant for your problem. You basically mean

```
val d = ft.select(convertToMapUDF(col("r_split")))
```

right?

Anyway,  what behavior do you expect for missing values (`null`)? I guess you want to skip them, that is keep `null`. This behavior is implemented in spark for  udfs working on non-nullable types (Float/Int/etc). For nullable types, including String, you need to implement it yourself.
Just check for `c == null` first thing in  the udf and return `null` in  that case. Sorry, I see that  your function returns `Option[Map[_,_]]`. In that case return `None`.

I think (not sure at the moment) you can also change your param to `Option[String]` but you will still have to process the `None` case yourself <strike>and perhaps `null` as well. I am a bit hazy on that.</strike>

Answer (score 1):

Nulls are coming from your dataset. You can make your udfs null safe with `cala.util.Try` (if you don't want to lose the record). Just wrap `convertToMapUDF` into Try construction. It will ensure any non-fatal exception is caught and a Failure object is returned.

```
def convertToMapUDF: UserDefinedFunction = udf((c: String) => {
    Try {
        val arr = c.split(",")
        val l = arr.toList

        val regexPattern = ".*(=).*".r

        println(s"column value: $c")

        s"$c" match {
            case regexPattern(a) => l.map(x => x.split("=")).map(a => a(0) -> a(1)).toMap
            case _ => Map[String, String]()
        }
    }.toOption
})
```

Comment: This approach has one major  drawback - in addition to intended action of ignoring nulls it suppresses any alerts about problems with code's logic.

Comment: It can be easily solved by unit testing the UDF.

Comment: Unit testing is always good, and in this case it may be enough, since the logic seems simple, but I don't like the catch all approach when it's just as easy to handle null values and let all other exceptions to go through and alert the user

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use a UDF here at all: Spark has all the functionality you need. Consider the following:

```
ft
  .withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
  .select(col("id"), explode(split(col("r_split"), ",")) as "r")
  .select(col("id"), split(col("r"), "=") as "s")
  .select(col("id"), map_from_arrays(array(col("s")(0)) as "k", array(col("s")(1)) as "v") as "map")
  .groupBy("id").agg(collect_list("map") as "maps")
  .select(
   aggregate(col("maps"), typedLit(Map[String, String]()), (acc, nxt) => map_concat(acc, nxt)) as "r_split"
  )
```

First we add an ID so we can put everything back together again at the end, then it takes your input string `r_split`, and breaks it on the ",". It then 'explodes' the resulting array so that each term has it's own `Row`. We then split the rows on the "=" symbol to create another array. Next we create a map by selecting the first element of the array as the key, and the second element as the value. This gives us a map for each entry, so we gather them together by ID (hence the first step) into a single list. Finally we reduce that list to a single map.

I feel there are too many steps here, and the various split/explode phases can probably we done more efficiently with `regexp_extract`, but this demonstrates the idea without having to use a UDF.